# How to validate a TOTP code generated from a flutter app in an ASP.NET Core site?

Tags: flutter, dart, asp.net-core, totp

I'm writing a simple 2FA application, which generates TOTP codes in a flutter app, then I want the user to enter this code in an ASP.NET Core site, but I can't validate the code in the site.

In Flutter/Dart, I am using the library  [dart-otp](https://github.com/daegalus/dart-otp) and in ASP.NET Core, I am using [kspearrin /Otp.NET](https://github.com/kspearrin/Otp.NET)

```
The code in Flutter/Dart is

    var now = DateTime.now();
    now = DateTime(2023, 04, 26, 10, 10, 10);

    var code = OTP.generateTOTPCodeString(
          'DDXFM42476476545', now.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
          algorithm: Algorithm.SHA256, isGoogle: false);

    print(code);  // Outputs 667099
```

In C# the code is

```
    string skey = "DDXFM42476476545";

    var  now = new DateTime(2023, 04, 26, 10, 10, 10);
    var totp = new Totp(Base32Encoding.ToBytes(skey),30,OtpHashMode.Sha256);
//var totp = new Totp(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(skey), 30, OtpHashMode.Sha256);

    var code = totp.ComputeTotp(now);//code : 734057
```

I don't know what is the problem of the code or if I am understanding something wrong?

Comment: It looks like the `dart-otp` library is [encoding the secret in utf8](https://github.com/daegalus/dart-otp/blob/master/lib/otp.dart#L96), while your provided C# code is encoding in Base32.

Comment: I have also tried using UTF-8 encoding, but without any match (this line is commented in the code ).

Comment: I see another issue but I'm not sure what the solution is exactly. Dart and C# are giving different values for milliseconds since epoch for those dates. In dart `DateTime(2023, 04, 26, 10, 10, 10).millisecondsSinceEpoch` gives `1682521810000`, while in C# `new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2023, 04, 26, 10, 10, 10)).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` gives `1682503810000`. I'm not sure why the difference, but maybe it can point you in the right direction.